# One-to-Many relation to existed table in EF6: The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

---

So now I'm trying to use Code first approach with a couple of existed tables.

So before now I have an existed table with model:

```
[Table("Existed1")]
public class TimeSerieEntity 
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [StringLength(3)]
    public string TsId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1, TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

And this entity illustrate time series element. So Now I need to add new Entity which has One-to-Many relation with this data. So I add class

```
public class TSRootEntity 
{
    [Key]
    [StringLength(3)]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TimeSerieEntity> Values { get; set; }
}
```

and change `TimeSerieEntity` to this one:

```
   [Table("Existed1")]
   public class TimeSerieEntity  
    {
        [Key, ForeignKey("TSMD")]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        [StringLength(3)]
        public string TsId { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1, TypeName = "date")]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        public double Value { get; set; }

        public virtual TSRootEntity TSMD { get; set; }
}
```

and add the following mapping:

```
`modelBuilder.Entity<TSRootEntity>()
                .HasMany(c => c.Values)
                .WithRequired(ts => ts.TSMD)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

But when I trying to run migration it fails with error:

```
{"'PK_dbo.Existed1' is not a constraint.\r\nCould not drop constraint. See previous errors."}
```

Please, help me to fix this.

---

For some reason it's try to use `PK_dbo.Existed1` but there is no such Constraint in DB, but there is `PK_Existed1` Why EF add this `dbo` prefix?

---

**UPD2:**

I solved 1st problem just with renaming PK constraint. But now I have different exception:

```
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Existed1_dbo.TSRootEntity_TsId". The conflict occurred in database "testdb", table "dbo.TSRootEntity", column 'Code'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Found the problem. So last error caused because of `Existed1` already have data, and `TSRootEntity` is empty. So it's try to map actuall foreign keys, to non existed primary keys. And that's make it fails.

So to solve that, we need prefill `TSRootEntity` as well. The question is - what is the most elegant way to do that?